# Appending first value of a list from a dictionary into the first value of another list; python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Working in Python 3.8.10

```
a = {'b': ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'f': ['g', 'h'], 'i': ['j']}
k = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l = {'b': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'a'], 'f': ['g', 'h', 'b'], 'i': ['j', 'c']}
```

I am trying to make a == l by putting the first value of k, 'a', into a['b'], the second value of k, 'b', into a['f'], and so on, until the last value of k. I have tried multiple ways like appending and looping over the keys using for loops but is having difficulty in finding a solution.

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: Also dict aren't ordered. 'The first key' makes no sense.

Comment: @Julien Since Python 3.7 dicts are officially ordered.

Comment: @MichaelButscher sure but if you care about order in a dict you probably chose the wrong data structure...

Comment: @Julien That's right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have tried multiple ways like appending and looping over the keys using for loops but is having difficulty in finding a solution." Can you show us any of these ways? What happened when you tried them? Why was none of them "a solution", and what "difficulty" did you have? Please read [ask]. We can only help you with code that you actually show to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a for-loop along with [`dict.values`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20values#dict.values) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a = {'b': ['c', 'd', 'e'], 'f': ['g', 'h'], 'i': ['j']}
>>> k = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l = {'b': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'a'], 'f': ['g', 'h', 'b'], 'i': ['j', 'c']}
>>> a == l
False
>>> for vals, v in zip(a.values(), k):
...     vals.append(v)
... 
>>> a
{'b': ['c', 'd', 'e', 'a'], 'f': ['g', 'h', 'b'], 'i': ['j', 'c']}
>>> a == l
True
```